# no commands found in cpdf

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to use cpdf to edit a pdf document. Specifically, I'm trying to rescale the page size by using the command

```
cpdf -scale-page "2 2" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

found in the documentation (https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf)

However, this gives me the error `No such command 'scale-page'`, and indeed when running `cpdf--help`, the scale-page command isn't present. What is going on here?

I'm using anaconda prompt if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:

```
./cpdf -scale-page "2 2" cpdfmanual.pdf -o out.pdf
```

"No such command" isn't a cpdf error. If you give an unknown command to cpdf you get:

```
$ cpdf -foo
cpdf: unknown option '-foo'. Use -help for help.
```

So it looks like whatever environment you're using isn't quoting this command properly, and `cpdf` is never being invoked.

Try it at a plain command line first. I am unfamiliar with Anaconda Prompt I'm afraid, but I suspect the answer lies there.